# How to bucketize using Query optimal bucketization algorithm

Tags: database-design, index, index-tuning, dbms

[image: Algorithm for query optimal bucketization]

I am trying to implement query optimal bucketization algorithm (QOB). The input of the algorithm is D=(V,F) where V is the value of the attribute and F is the frequency of occurrence. 
For EXAMPLE
D = {(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 10), (5, 10), (6, 4), (7, 6), (8,
2), (9, 4), (10, 2) } is the INPUT. The OUTPUT of the algorithm is the minimum bucket cost and partition point.

Say the maximum number of buckets allowed is 4 (M=4). The minimum value of the cost function comes out to be = 120 after executing the algorithm.

In the given algorithm H matrix stores bucket costs and OPP matrix stores optimal partition points. Now I have got H matrix and OPP matrix. I didn't understand how to use this OPP matrix to make partitions. In the given example the partition is done like this

```
{1, 2, 3 }, {4, 5, 6 }, {7 }, {8, 9, 10 }
```

And minimum cost of bucketization is 120. Please help me find the partition points using OPP matrix.

I have attached the screen shot which shows the details of H and OPP matrix   [image]